# Possible to call a Flash (AS3) function when dynamic scrolling text has reached the bottom?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Would like to perform an animation after the user has scrolled to the bottom of a dynamic textbox in Flash AS3. Text is loaded dynamically, if that matters.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  If so, please accept the answer or add your own (if the answer provided was not suitable), if not, please update the question to show your progress.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
        myTextField.addEventListener(Event.SCROLL, scrollHandler);

        function scrollHandler(e:Event):void {
            if (myTextField.scrollV >= myTextField.maxScrollV) {
                trace("You've Reached The End - It happens to us all eventually");
                //do your animation
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched and lastly deploy in my project. It is working code. Thank you very much SO for giving me most of the solutions.

```
private var mcScrolll:mcScroll;
        private var mcBolgee:mcBolge;
        private function Scroll_Method_New():void 
        {
            tempBGBmp = new TempBG();
            this.addChild(tempBGBmp);
            tempBGBmp.x = 0;            
            tempBGBmp.y = 0;


            if (!trainer_Maria_text)    
                trainer_Maria_text = new TextField();
            createTextWithXY(trainer_Maria_text, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas at augue vitae est bibendum egestas. Fusce molestie felis nec arcu tincidunt dictum. Morbi dapibus vitae tortor non fringilla. Proin consectetur sapien ut eleifend ullamcorper. Duis blandit laoreet hendrerit. Duis sit amet massa sit amet tortor consequat dignissim sed vitae nisl. Vivamus vel lobortis odio. Sed id posuere dolor, eget auctor est. Donec sapien libero, bibendum ac .", 0, 0, 400, 41 );

            //trainer_Maria_text.scrollRect = view;
            //tempBGBmp.bar
            //trainer_Maria_text.scrollRect.x = 50;
            //trainer_Maria_text.scrollRect.y = 50;
             //trainer_Maria_text.scrollV = 1;


            /*mcScrollZone = new mcScrollZonecopy();
            this.addChild(mcScrollZone);
            mcScrollZone.x = 0;
            mcScrollZone.y = 0;*/

            mcScrolll = new mcScroll();
            this.addChild(mcScrolll);
            mcScrolll.x = 600;
            mcScrolll.y = 50;

            mcBolgee = new mcBolge();
            this.addChild(mcBolgee);
            mcBolgee.x = 600;
            mcBolgee.y = 50;

            var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(mcBolgee.x, mcBolgee.y, 0, mcBolgee.height - 90);

            //MouseWheelTrap.setup(stage);

            mcScrolll.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, StartDrag);
            //mcScrolll.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_, StartDrag);

            mcScrolll.buttonMode = true;
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, StopStageDrag);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, ScrollBody);
            //mcScrollZone.mcText.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, SetScroll);
            //tempBGBmp.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, SetScroll);

            /*function SetScroll(event:Event):void
            { 
                            mcScrolll.y = 295;
                            //mcScrollZone.y = -(((mcScrolll.y - mcBolgee.y)*((mcScrollZone.height /*- mcMask.height*/)/(295 - mcBolgee.y)))) + mcBolgee.y;
                            tempBGBmp.y = -(((mcScrolll.y - mcBolgee.y)*((tempBGBmp.height /*- mcMask.height*/)/(295 - mcBolgee.y)))) + mcBolgee.y;
                            trainer_Maria_text.y = -(((mcScrolll.y - mcBolgee.y)*((trainer_Maria_text.height /*- mcMask.height*/)/(295 - mcBolgee.y)))) + mcBolgee.y;
            }*/
            var control:Boolean = false;
            function StopStageDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                            if(control)
                            {
                                    mcScrolll.gotoAndStop(1);
                                    control = false;
                                    mcScrolll.stopDrag();
                            }
            }
            function StartDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                            event.currentTarget.gotoAndStop(2);
                            control = true;
                            event.currentTarget.startDrag(false,rect);
            }
            function ScrollBody(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                            //mcScrollZone.mcText.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
                            if(control)
                            {
                                //mcScrollZone.y = -(((mcScrolll.y - mcBolgee.y)*((mcScrollZone.height /*- mcMask.height*/)/(296 - mcBolgee.y)))) + mcBolgee.y;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                tempBGBmp.y = -(((mcScrolll.y - mcBolgee.y)*((tempBGBmp.height /*- mcMask.height*/)/(296 - mcBolgee.y)))) + mcBolgee.y;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                trainer_Maria_text.y = -(((mcScrolll.y - mcBolgee.y)*((trainer_Maria_text.height /*- mcMask.height*/)/(296 - mcBolgee.y)))) + mcBolgee.y;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                            }
            }
```